# Accessing index values before and after symbol from input

Tags: java

I am trying to take the input and if there is an @ symbol in the input then it finds the maximum of the integers before and after the @ symbol. The maximum part I have no problem with but I do not know how to access and find the values before and after the @ symbol.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Max_Min {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //gets keyboard
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        //puts input into string
        String inputString = keyboard.nextLine();
        //splits string between characters
        String[] splitInput = inputString.split("");

        for (String s : splitInput) {
            if(s.equals("@")){ 
                //computes the maximum of the two integers before and after the @ 
            }


        }

        //close keyboard
        keyboard.close();
```

I did do a search to find something simliar (and im sure there is something) but could not find anything. If someone could help that would be great!

Comment: As you can see from the different answers, the instruction "the maximum of the integers before and after the @ symbol" can be interpreted in many different ways. Do you have some example inputs and the corresponding outputs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < splitInput.length; i++){
    if (splitInput[i].equals("@") && i != 0 && i != splitInput.length -1){
        int max = Math.max(Integer.parseInt(splitInput[i - 1]), Integer.parseInt(splitInput[i + 1]));
    }
    //...
}
```

Comment: Thank you!! If I wanted to use the variable max outside of the for and if. How would I do that?

Comment: @Forextrader you could declare **int max** outside the for, but if you do that, you will only save the last max value gotten inside the for.

Answer (score 1):

You could try:

```
String[] splitInput = inputString.split("@");
```

which would split your string at the @s.
Then you can do a iteration over your splitInput array and do a .length on each index.

Answer (score 1):

You have written the simple `for` loop, with which you can only access the string, but not its index in the array. If you had the index, you could write:

```
int possibleMax = Integer.parseInt(splitInput[i - 1]) + Integer.parseInt(splitInput[i + 1]);
```

To get the index, there are two ways:

```
for (int i = 0; i < splitInput.length; i++) {
    String s = splitInput[i];
    ...
}
```

Or:

```
int i = 0;
for (String s : splitInput) {
    …
    i++;
}
```

I don't like either version because both are more complicated than absolutely necessary, in terms of written code. If you would use Kotlin instead of Java, it would be:

```
splitInput.forEachIndexed { i, s ->
    …
}
```

In Java this could be written:

```
forEachIndexed(
    splitInput,
    (i, s) -> …
);
```

The problem in Java is that the code inside the … cannot update the variables of the enclosing method. I'm not sure whether this will ever change. It would be possible but needs a lot of work by the language committee.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to do this would be

```
String input = "12@23";
String [] arr = input.split("@");
if (arr.length == 2) {
    System.out.println("Max is "+Math.max(Integer.valueOf(arr[0]),Integer.valueOf(arr[1])));
}
```